# Apply tags to Azure resource group within resource template file

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm using Powershell to create an Azure resource group from a template file and parameter file.

```
New-AzureResourceGroup  -Name $groupName `
                    -TemplateFile $templateFile `
                    -TemplateParameterFile $paramFile `
                    -Location $location `
                    -Force -Verbose
```

Within the template I'm setting some tags on the resources within the group.

**resourcegroup.json**

```
    "parameters": {
        "environment": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Dev",
            "Test",
            "QA",
            "Prod"
        ]}
    }
....
    "resources": [
    {
        ...
        "tags": {
            "Environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        }
    }
```

I'd like to apply the same tag values to the resource group itself, but I don't see a way to do that within the schema of the template file.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now at least, this is possible:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/tags",
      "name": "default",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "resource1"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "tags": {
          "Tag1": "Value1",
          "Tag2": "Value2"
        }
      }
    }
```

Documentation reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/tags)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to use the azure Powershell command-let to add tags to your Azure Resource group. It cannot be done through the Template file.